# Why can't I access settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm needing some scope help. Below is my code (simplified). Within a function within the success event of an ajax call within buildDropdownOptions... (mouthful).

I'm attempting to set something in a settings object that's at the same level as buildDropdownOptions, yet I'm unable to access it (maybe because of the AJAX call?).

Does anyone know how to get this thing to work?

```
var settings = {},
buildDropdownOptions = function () {

                    var success = function (clinics, settings) {
                        var dropdownOptions = [];

                        $.each(clinics, function (i, clinic) {
                            dropdownOptions.push('<option value="' + clinic.ClinicId + '">' + clinic.Name + '</option>');
                        });

                        settings.dropdown.options = dropdownOptions;
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        'url': settings.dropdown.source,
                        'success': function (clinics, settings) {
                            success(clinics);
                        }
                    });
                };
```

Answer (score 5):

By including `settings` as a function parameter, you are hiding the higher-level `settings` variable.

In fact, in this case you are hiding it with `undefined`.

Remove the `settings` mentioned in the argument list and it should work fine.

Comment: Ok, removed that parameter. Now, logging dropdownOptions within success(), after the $.each correctly. However, I want to set settings.dropdown.options to dropdownOptions and it's still not working. Also, I've already defined that key in my object, just removed it in the example to keep things clean, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you cannot access settings.dropdown property. Try to change the first line of your code to:

```
var settings = {dropdown: {}}:
```